How to find $\alpha$ where :$\text{sup}(|f|+|g|)\ge \alpha(\text{sup}(|f|) +\text{sup}(|g|))$
$f$ and $g$ two function continu
How to find $\alpha$ where :$$\text{sup}(|f|+|g|)\ge  \alpha(\text{sup}(|f|) +\text{sup}(|g|))$$
I know this is true :
$$\text{sup}(|f|+|g|)\le \text{sup}(|f|) +\text{sup}(|g|)$$

What have you tried? Why do you expect to find such an $\alpha$, is this an exercise or a conjecture/personal problem?

Personal proplem

Hint: $\sup |f| + |g| \geq \max(\sup |f| + \sup |g|) \geq \dots$. Try to find an example for why the constant you'll obtain from that consideration is optimal, for example with positive functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f + g = 1$ and $\sup f = \sup g = 1$.
